# Integral $\int \frac{x}{2-\cos(2x)} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

A friend of mine told me that a friend of his who is a first year undergraduate had this integral on an exam, and that noone was able to solve it.

$$\int \frac{x}{2-\cos(2x)} dx$$

The function has periodic singularities, which is kind of problematic since it's indefinite. The answer given by WolframAlpha is even more problematic: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+x%2F%282-cos%282x%29%29.

But I'm told that there is an 'elementary' solution. Is there?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no elementary solution for the integral. The closed form involves the polylogarithm function.

Comment: Perhaps a test typo?  Something like $2-\cos^2(x)$ in the denominator?

Comment: Don't always believe W/A when it says "no elementary solution can be found". For example W/A can't find a solution to $$\int\sqrt{\frac{x^2-1}{2x^2-x^4}}dx,$$ but this was an exercise on university and it does have a nice solution.

Comment: @barto: True enough, but I would be more willing to believe Integrals and Series when he says so.

Comment: @barto I tried the integral you've given in W/A and indeed it says that it have a *nice* solution.

Comment: Indeed, something with a bunch of nested $\text{(arc)sin}$, $\cos$, $\tan$ and some $\sqrt2$ stuff if I remember well. (There should be an equivalent form with these compositions replaced by square-root like formulae, too.) Evaluating the integral by hand is not that hard, the substitutions (6 or so in total) are quite natural given the form of the integrand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by   *Integrals and Series* that integral unfortunately doesn't have a "nice" closed form. The best you can get is a long expression involving polylogarithms:

$$\frac1{4 \sqrt{3}}{i \left(i \left(\text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{\left(-2+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(-i+\sqrt{3} \tan (x)\right)}{i+\sqrt{3} \tan (x)}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{\left(2+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(-i+\sqrt{3} \tan (x)\right)}{i+\sqrt{3} \tan (x)}\right)\right)+2 i \cos ^{-1}(2) \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{3} \tan (x)\right)+4 i x \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\cot (x)}{\sqrt{3}}\right)-\left(2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{3} \tan (x)\right)+\cos ^{-1}(2)\right) \log \left(\frac{\left(\sqrt{3}-3\right) (\cos (x)-i \sin (x))}{-\cos (x)+i \sqrt{3} \sin (x)}\right)-\left(\cos ^{-1}(2)-2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{3} \tan (x)\right)\right) \log \left(\frac{\left(3+\sqrt{3}\right) (\cos (x)+i \sin (x))}{\cos (x)-i \sqrt{3} \sin (x)}\right)+\log \left(\frac{i \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} e^{-i x}}{\sqrt{\cos (2 x)-2}}\right) \left(2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{3} \tan (x)\right)+2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\cot (x)}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+\cos ^{-1}(2)\right)+\log \left(\frac{i \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} e^{i x}}{\sqrt{\cos (2 x)-2}}\right) \left(-2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{3} \tan (x)\right)-2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\cot (x)}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+\cos ^{-1}(2)\right)\right)}{}.$$